# Can we run U-SQL query in oozie workflow in HDInsight

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

we can run U-SQL Query using Azure data factory.

can we run U-SQL query using  oozie workflow in HDINSIGHT Spark cluster.

Answer (score 1):

(Azure Data Lake team here)

Currently the U-SQL language is only supported running in a Data Lake Analytics account. HDInsight doesn't support running U-SQL in a cluster.